# Starting an app through code with a relative path in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfsbuild

Can anyone explain to me how to navigate to a relative path using

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

or something similar?

I want to start up a web service from inside my unit tests. i know how to get the relative path of the unit test like above or using the system reflection version but i do no know how to navigate using it.

The unit test is in a separate project in visual studio with separate folders than the service but they are both in the same solution so the path relative to one another is always the same but i do not know to use that with

```
Process.Start
```

so i can tell it to start the service.

If anyone knows please let me know, or if by chance you know another way to start a web service in TFS automated builds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a object called "System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo" which can help you to invoke an external process or start an application from your .NET application. Traversing to the folder can be done using some kind of Path.Combine() methods and you can pass the same path where the application lies to the "WorkingDirectory" property of ProcessStartInfo object.

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(string.Format("cmd /c start some service"))
            {
                WorkingDirectory = ==PathWhereApplicationIs==,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                ErrorDialog = false,
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                RedirectStandardError = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
            };
```

In above code snippet : cmd is the command prompt, /c is the indication that we are passing some arguments, the rest can be any command you wish to execute

Comment: i noticed path.combine() while searching but i don't understand how to use it for what i want. i don't have anything exact. i have the relative path of my unit test and i can figure out how to navigate the folder tree(ex: go up 3 directories then enter x folder then inside the y folder etc)

Comment: You can use the Directory.GetParent("some path") three times to navigate 3 directories up and then sue Path.Combine("3directoriesUpPath", "newFolderName") to go in the final directory you have your application to execute.

Comment: oh so that's how. i figured there must be some commands to navigate away from a relative path. thank you.